# How to write file data correctly?

Tags: java, io, filestream, large-files

My application is unable to transfer data properly over a socket connection and write it to a file properly. Files over about 65,535 bytes get corrupted and are no longer recognized by the programs designed to run them.

I have been able to send small .doc and .txt files successfully, but .mp3 .wmv .m4a .avi and just about anything else does not work.  Neither do larger docs.

I have looked all over the internet for a solution to this problem.  I have repeatedly tweaked the I/O code to fix the problem but it still doesn't work!  Here is the I/O code in the super class that handles sending and receiving files.  If you need anymore information/other parts of code, let me know.

```
protected void sendFile() throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    buffin = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    int bytesRead = buffin.read(bytes,0,bytes.length);
    System.out.println(bytesRead);
    out = sock.getOutputStream();
    out.write(bytes,0,fileBytes);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}

protected void receiveFile() throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[fileBytes];
    in = sock.getInputStream();
    for(int i=0;i<fileBytes;i++) {
        in.read(bytes);
    }
    fos = new FileOutputStream("/Datawire/"+fileName);
    buffout = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    buffout.write(bytes,0,fileBytes);
    buffout.flush();
    buffout.close();
}
```

UPDATED CODE (that works):

```
    protected void sendFile() throws IOException {
    if((file.length())<63000) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)file.length()];
        buffin = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        buffin.read(bytes,0,bytes.length);
        out = sock.getOutputStream();
        out.write(bytes,0,bytes.length);
        out.close();
    } else {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[32000];
        buffin = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        out = sock.getOutputStream();
        int bytesRead;
        while((bytesRead = buffin.read(bytes))>0) {
            out.write(bytes,0,bytesRead);
        }
        out.close();
    }
}

protected void receiveFile() throws IOException {
    if(fileBytes<63000) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[32000];
        in = sock.getInputStream();
        System.out.println(in.available());
        in.read(bytes,0,fileBytes);
        fos = new FileOutputStream("/Datawire/"+fileName);
        buffout = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        buffout.write(bytes,0,bytes.length);
        buffout.close();
    } else {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[16000];
        in = sock.getInputStream();
        fos = new FileOutputStream("/Datawire/"+fileName);
        buffout = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        int bytesRead;
        while((bytesRead = in.read(bytes))>0) {
            buffout.write(bytes,0,bytesRead);
        }
        buffout.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: How does the receiver know how many bytes to read?  Seems like you are missing that.  You assume a size, read until that size is met, and write the file to disk.

Comment: @Rob_Goodwin Notice the send and receive information methods that run before the file is sent.  The information such as the filename and file size are sent to the receiving end there.  The file size is represented by the variable fileBytes for the receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is completely wrong. This is how to copy a stream in Java:

```
int count;
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // more if you like but no need for it to be the entire file size
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
  out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

You should use this both when sending the file and when receiving the file. At present your sending method hopes that the entire file fits into memory; fits into INTEGER_MAX bytes; and is read in one chunk by the read method, without even checking the result. You can't assume any of those things. Your receive method is complete rubbish: it just keeps overwriting the same array, again without checking any read() results.

**EDIT:** Your revised code is just as bad, or worse. You are calling read() to check for EOS and then throwing that byte away, and then calling read() again and throwing away the read count it returns. You pointlessly have a different path for files < 64000, or 63000, or whatever it is, that has zero benefit except to give you two code paths to test, or possibly four, instead of one. The network only gives you 1460 bytes at a time at best anyway so what is the point? You already have (a) a BufferedInputStream with a default buffersize of 8192, and (b) my code that uses a byte[] buffer of any size you like. My code above works for any amount of data in two lines of executable code. Yours is 20. QED.

Comment: Well um... thanks for the help?  A little harsh but... I'm not super experienced with I/O.  I've been playing with various forms of sending and receiving.

Comment: Well it was intended to get your attention ;-)

Comment: Fair enough.  Could you explain this to me though?  I tried it in my code and it didn't work.  The input still didn't read all of the bytes.

Comment: Can this method be used with a buffered input/output stream?

Comment: @ghostsoldier23 More probably you haven't closed/flushed the output so you missed writing the last buffer. Yes it can be used with BufferedInput/OutputStream.

Comment: I posted the updated code in the OP.  Now it does read all of the data, but writes a file much larger than the original.  Like it's creating blank bytes... and a lot of them.  I changed your method a bit... because I couldn't get it to work exactly.

Comment: @ghostsoldier23 There's only one way to say this. All you've done here is just added more rubbish. I gave you working code. Use it. It has been working for me for 14 years. You don't need to alter a syllable of it apart from the variable names.

Comment: Ha well thanks for the brutal criticism.  I will give it another go.

Comment: Thanks!  It worked!  I should never have doubted you!  Check OP for the updated code... that works!

Comment: @ghostsoldier23 Your special case for < 63000 is still (a) wrong and (b) pointless.

Comment: No I see no reason in wasting time with a buffering system if I can just easily write the bytes straight in.  And besides the code was already there...

Comment: @ghostsoldier23 the code concerned remains incorrect. If you remove it it will become correct. If you fix it it will also become correct, but the only way to fix it is to make it identical to the other branch apart from the buffer size. You don't seem to appreciate what is wrong with it, as the existence and history of this thread both exhibit in spades. Why not just use a larger buffer size and the same piece of code?

Comment: I ended up taking your advice and removing it all together.  I also increased the buffer size to 100,000 :D

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are sending only chunks of it.  That is, you are only sending 64k of the file ever.  If the file is ever larger then 64k the other end will never see it.

You want to continously read from the BufferedInputStream until the read() returns either less then the length or -1.

Comment: @John_V. Which part of the code are you referring to?  Which BufferedInputStream?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use some good library to read and write file contents as well as socket read/write. For example Apache Commons IO. If you insist on writig code yourself, do it smaller chunks rather than the whole file at once.

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider that [InputStream.read](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) returns the number of bytes read which may be less than the total number of bytes in the file.

You would probably be better off just letting something like [CopyUtils.copy](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/CopyUtils.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) take care of this for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop until bytesRead < 0. You need to make sure that *fileBytes* is => than the transferred file.

```
protected void receiveFile() throws IOException {
    byte [] bytes  = new byte [fileBytes];
    InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/Datawire/"+fileName);
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

    int bytesRead = is.read(bytes,0,bytes.length);
    int current = bytesRead;

    do {
       bytesRead =
          is.read(bytes, current, (bytes.length-current));
       if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
    } while(bytesRead > -1);

    bos.write(bytes, 0 , current);
    bos.flush();
    bos.close();

}
```

Comment: @ghostsoldier23, my solution will write the received data using *current* as the actual length. So even if filesBytes is greater, only the received data will be written.